# View XML in Rails Console in a neatly nested format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, console

In Rails Console, I am seeing output like:

```
<AmazonProduct::Response:0x00000102dd9070 @body=\"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" ?><ItemSearchResponse xmlns=\\\"http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01\\\"><OperationRequest><HTTPHeaders><Header Name=\\\"UserAgent\\\" Value=\\\"Ruby\\\"></Header></HTTPHeaders><RequestId>13a86d54-dc7c-4ee1-afc2-26bdeadfd914</RequestId><Arguments><Argument Name=\\\"Operation\\\" Value=\\\"ItemSearch\\\"></Argument><Argument Name=\\\"Service\\\" Value=\\\"AWSECommerceService\\\"></Argument> etc etc
```

Is there a gem that will automatically nest it all nicely, like this:

```
<SubTotal>
  <Amount>2998</Amount>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
  <FormattedPrice>$29.98</FormattedPrice>
</SubTotal>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `nokogiri` can do the trick.
Look at this [article](http://vitobotta.com/more-methods-format-beautify-ruby-output-console-logs/)